# Emulate SQL Server Update in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

How could I emulate the following SQL Server query in Oracle?

```
declare @index = 4
update tablex set
    id_product = @index
    , @index = @index + 1
where Id_Person = 4037
```

In SQL Server it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking what would be the equivalent of the SQL Server code:

```sql
DECLARE @index INT = 4
UPDATE tablex SET id_product = @index, @index = @index + 1 where Id_Person = 4037
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rowiRkg3)

Then you can use a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE tablex__id_product__seq START WITH 5;

UPDATE tablex
SET   id_product = tablex__id_product__seq.NEXTVAL
WHERE Id_Person = 4037
```

or could use `ROWNUM`:

```sql
UPDATE tablex
SET   id_product = 4 + ROWNUM
WHERE Id_Person = 4037
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nTTl45DV)